# How to switch classes onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

thank you for reading this. I am attempting to learn React by making a dummy website, however I've run into a roadblock.

I want the `"display-page"` div to only show the `Send`  element initially (which is easy) but when someone clicks one of the 4 options from the `content_bar` div I want remove the current element and only show the newly clicked element (in this case it is 'Transactions')

I've read about useState and routing but I'm not sure how to implement

Thanks! Please let me know if I didnt give enough details

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Data.css';
import Transactions from './Transactions';
import Send from './Send';



class Data extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: <Send />
        }
      }

      transactionpage = () => {
            this.setState({content: <Transactions/>});
      }

    
    render() {

        return(
            <div className="content">
                <div className="content_bar">
                    <h5>Send</h5>
                    <h5 onClick={this.transactionpage}>Transactions</h5>
                    <h5>Friends</h5>
                    <h5>Professional</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="display-page">
                  {this.state.content}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's ok that you are learning, but SO isn't a code writing service. Please do attempt this on your own first and if you are stuck then update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Even if it's not working that is ok. Please also include all relevant details about issues, bugs, expected vs actual results, reproduction steps, etc, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at  You can't press an `<h5>` tag and React code without state feels strange.

You need to learn more to achieve your goal, these are the topics:

- JSX expresssion
- Conditional rendering
- State management

Let me show you my solution, it is one of many ways.

```js
class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toDisplay: ''
    };
    this.changeToDisplay = this.changeToDisplay.bind(this);
  }
  changeToDisplay(e) {
    this.setState({ toDisplay: e.target.textContent.toString() });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content_bar">
          <button onClick={e => changeToDisplay(e)}>Send</button> <br />
          <button onClick={e => changeToDisplay(e)}>Transactions</button> <br />
          <button>Friends</button> <br />
          <button>Professional</button> <br />
        </div>
        <div className="display-page">
          {this.state.toDisplay === 'Send' ? <Send /> : null}
          {this.state.toDisplay === 'Transactions' ? <Transactions /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: idk I used this exact code and I'm still getting the same errors, youre right I should have used state.... I updated my latest code too btw in the question

Comment: I've got it working my example worked.... and yes you can click headers brother I just did it

Comment: @WesleyBond Glad you figured it out, I answered your question using the old code

Comment: @WesleyBond now I realize headers can be clicked but it's not used often so I find it weird